# Performance of redirecting image requests

Tags: node.js, image, express

Currently I'm storing a lot of static image files on my own Node-Express server, and accessing them throughout the code via relative url (ex: `<img src="/img/foo/bar.png">`). I'm moving all the images to Amazon S3, so now this url would have to be `https://myimagebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/img/foo/bar.png`. However, changing every single image reference to include this absolute url would be a nightmare, so I set up some Express middleware that would redirect any image requests like so:

```
app.use('/img', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('https://myimagebucket.s3.amazonaws.com' + req.originalUrl); 
});
```

Performance-wise, is this a good idea, or does this negate the benefits of hosting the images somewhere else?

Or is it best practice to specify the host in the view, meaning I should just take the long route of changing all of the image references manually?

Comment: I don't see any performance issues with it, but from a long run perspective you should plan on eventually switching the URLs over.

Comment: Don't forget to add `cache-control` header to tell browsers to cache redirect paths.